# background and run continuous without close

Tags: java, android

I make mobile lost gps tracking application, that code will be running in only activity..

my application strategy is.

1) if found `http://192.168.43.164/imei_000000000000000.txt` file then find
"track" or "find_mobile" string in `imei_000000000000000.txt`.

2) if "track" or "find_mobile" string is found in `imei_000000000000000.txt` file then post

"http://192.168.43.164/add.php?long_itude=22.00023&lat_itude=22.00023." link

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
                        try{
                            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.164/imei_000000000000000.txt");
                            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                            String str;
                            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                            {
                                urls.add(str);
                            }
                            in.close();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                li = urls.get(0);
                                if (li.equals("track") || li.equals("find_mobile")) {
                                    try{
                                        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.43.164/add.php?long_itude=22.00023&lat_itude=22.00023");
                                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                                        String str;
                                        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                                        {
                                            urls.add(str);
                                        }
                                        in.close();
                                    } catch (Exception e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "not found"+ li, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        } );
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        },5,5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

posted code will work fine, but it's code working only in activity.

I want make that code background and run continuous without close.

Answer (score -1):

use new thread = (Thread)  function

Comment: I want that code run in background process all time (run continously ) when Internet is on